# Yet another antiforgery token issue in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I am getting the below exception in one scenario.

System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

I have a get and post method for change password.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword()
    {
      Return View();
    }

 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(PasswordModel passwordModel)
    {
      if(some validation exception)
       {
          return View(passwordModel);
       }

    }
```

My form is as below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "User", FormMethod.Post, ))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    form elements
 }
```

When there is no validation failures, there is no antiforgery exception. But when there is an validation error and I am redirecting back I am getting this error. Any help regarding this is appreciated. TIA